# useState Array boolean toggle - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Beginner developer react native.

im dealing with design pattern issue ,
i have multiple TouchableOpacity's in the same component (i have to keep it that way).
for each one i have onPress function thats changs there background and reverse .
the problom is that the function dependent on State current statment and when i click on one of them evreyone is changing .

```
function Grocery({ navigation }) {

  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(0);
  const onPress = () => setIsPressed(!isPressed);



  return (  
    
    <ScrollView>
      <Button title="home" onPress={() => {FindMatch(GetIngridients());navigation.navigate("MatchedRecipiesScreen");}}>press</Button>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => {AddToPanetry("pasta");onPress();}}  >
    <View style={isPressed && styles.pressedButtonStyle} />
        <Image style={styles.imageright} source={require('../assets/Pastaa.jpg')} />
        <Text> pasta</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>



      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {AddToPanetry("eggs");onPress();}}  >
      <View style={isPressed && styles.pressedButtonStyle} />
        <Image style={styles.imageleft} source={require('../assets/eggs.jpg')} />
        <Text>eggs</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>




      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {AddToPanetry("fish");onPress();}}  >
      <View style={isPressed && styles.pressedButtonStyle} />
        <Image style={styles.imageleft} source={require('../assets/fish.jpg')} />
        <Text>fish</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    padding: 50,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  }
  ,
  imageleft: {
    borderRadius:100,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderColor:'black',
    height: 120,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 80,
    padding:25
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
   
  },
    tinyLogo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  pressedButtonStyle: {
    position:"absolute",
    width:150,
    height:121,
    backgroundColor:'black',
    opacity:0.6,
    zIndex:100,
    borderRadius:80
  },
  imageright: {
    borderRadius:100,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderColor:'black',
    height: 120,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 80,
    padding:25
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code have some things that must be improved. First at all, can you please put the code of the `AddToPanetry`function? You can edit the question and add it as well.

Answer (score 4):

One of the approaches is to store item names in an array or object and then check if the particular item were selected.

Here is another approach you could use:

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
    const itemsData = [
        { name: 'Eggs', image: 'image require here', isSelected: false },
        { name: 'Pasta', image: '', isSelected: false },
        { name: 'Fish', image: '', isSelected: false },
    ];

    const [items, setItems] = useState(itemsData);

    const handleSelectItem = (selectedItemIndex) => {
        const itemsToSelect = items.map((item, index) => {
        if (selectedItemIndex === index) item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
        return item;
        }, []);

        setItems(itemsToSelect);

        // your logic here
        // AddToPanetry(item[selectedItemIndex].name)
    };

    const renderItem = (item, index) => {
        const isSelected = items[index].isSelected;

        return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.button, isSelected && styles.selectedButton]}
            onPress={() => handleSelectItem(index)}>
            {/* <Image source={item.image} /> */}
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };

    return (
        <View>
        <ScrollView>
            {itemsData.map((item, index) => renderItem(item, index))}
        </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 20,
  },
  selectedButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
});
```

Comment: Tnx ! any idea why i have to click twice beofre its works?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options depending on your needs.

1. You could keep your all of your data and `selected` state in a single stateful array. On press, you need to find the item in the array that will update.

```
export default function Grocery({ navigation }) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([ { label: 'pasta', pressed: false, }, { label: 'eggs', pressed: false, }, { label: 'fish', pressed: false, }, { label: 'salad', pressed: false, }, ]);

  const handlePress = (i) => {
    const newState = [...state];
    newState[i].pressed = !state[i].pressed;
    setState(newState);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={state}
        ListHeaderComponent={() => (
          <Button
            title="home"
            onPress={() => {console.log('press home')}}>
            press
          </Button>
        )}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            id={index}
            onPress={() => handlePress(index)}
            style={[
              styles.flatListTouchable,
              item.pressed && styles.flatListTouchablePressed,
            ]}>
            <Text style={styles.flatListTouchableText}>{item.label}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

[Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ksav/hot-mixed-nuts)

---

2. You could keep your data and `selected` state separately. The `selected` state is managed in the child component.

```
const data = [ { label: 'pasta', }, { label: 'eggs', }, { label: 'fish', }, { label: 'salad', }, ];

export default function Grocery({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        ListHeaderComponent={() => (
          <Button
            title="home"
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('press home');
            }}>
            press
          </Button>
        )}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <RenderItem item={item} index={index} />
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const RenderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = React.useState(false);

  const handlePress = () => {
    setPressed(!pressed);
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={index}
      id={index}
      onPress={handlePress}
      style={[
        styles.flatListTouchable,
        pressed && styles.flatListTouchablePressed,
      ]}>
      <Text style={styles.flatListTouchableText}>{item.label}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

[Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ksav/lonely-soylent)